# Synchronous video viewing over the internet

Tags: windows, video, internet, sync

I'm looking for a program or web app where I can view a video file (.avi) with somebody over the internet synchronously; does anybody know of such a thing?

Comment: Skype them and say "Ready... GO!"

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to stream through VLC, depending on your available network speeds. "Ready... GO!" has worked for me in the past though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in all seriousness, iChat on OS X can do this with a feature called iChat Theater. You start a video chat with a buddy and then share the AVI file with iChat Theater from the File menu. As long as you've got the necessary codecs for your QuickTime it'll allow you both to view the content *and* a webcam feed simultaneously.

Comment: That's a helpful answer; unfortunately, I'm on Windows, which I should have specified in the question. I'm surprised that not many other people want a program with this sort of functionality, but ultimately your comment on the original question is probably the best way of going about it.